# Matplotlib plot bar graph with maximum length

Tags: matplotlib, graph

I am using Matplotlib to plot a bar graph. Most of my data values are in the range of -10 to +30. However, I have two data values that are around -300.

When I plot my data, the -300 data value bar looks too big, and it hides the insights of the other bars. Is there a way that I can plot all bars in -10 to +30 range, clip the -300 bar at -30 and instead write a label "-300"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`ax.set_ylim()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) to set the ylimits, and [`ax.annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) to write the label (and, if you like, an arrow).

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

y = [-5, 10, 25, -10, 30, -300, 20, 30, -10, -300, 0, 4]
x = range(len(y))

ax.bar(x, y, width=1, alpha=0.5)

ymin, ymax = -15, 35
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)

for xbar,ybar in zip(x,y):

    if ybar < ymin:

        ax.annotate(
                ybar, 
                xy=(xbar+0.5, -14), 
                xytext=(xbar+0.5, -8),
                rotation=90, ha='center', va='center',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

plt.show()
```

[image]